# How to update different collections of one object by some value using one method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have two identical methods that update a list by some value:

```
 def block_device(self, device_id):
    if self.block_device_ids is None:
        self.block_device_ids = []
    if device_id not in self.block_device_ids:
        self.block_device_ids.append(device_id)
        self.save()
        return True
    return False

 def add_video(self, video_id):
    if self.video_ids is None:
        self.video_ids = []
    if video_id not in self.video_ids:
        self.video_ids.append(video_id)
        self.save()
        return True
    return False
```

How to create one method `update_collection`and use it in both cases?

I created the following solution:

```
async def update_collection(self, collection, item, attr_name):
    if collection is None:
        collection = []
    if item not in collection:
        getattr(self, attr_name).append(item)
        await self.save()
        return True
    return False

 async def add_video(self, video_id):
    return await self.update_collection(self.video_ids, video_id, 'video_ids')

 async def block_device(self, device_id):
    return await self.update_collection(self.block_device_ids, device_id, 'device_ids')
```

but it doesn't work because of `collection = []`. How to fix this?
Is there anything that I can improve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass in the collection *and* the name of the attribute:

```
async def update_collection(self, item, attr_name):
    collection = getattr(self, attr_name)
    if collection is None:
        setattr(self, attr_name, [])
        collection = getattr(self, attr_name)
    if item not in collection:
        collection.append(item)
        await self.save()
        return True
    return False
```

NOTE: You have a bug on the last line of your code: the attr_name passed in should be "block_device_ids" not "device_ids"